# How do I configure syntax highlighting for LESS in coda?

Tags: css, syntax-highlighting, less, coda

I use [LESS.app](http://incident57.com/less/) for less compiling but it doesn't help with Coda not having syntax highlighting for CSS/LESS within the `.less` file.

How do I force Coda to highlight css/less syntax within the .less file.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110014/coda-syntax-highlighting-for-silverstripe) is the same problem, same solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out by creating a LESS "modes" folder.

- Right click on the Coda Application within "**Applications**"
- Select "**Package Contents**"
- "**Contents**"
- "**Resources**"
- "**Modes**"
- Then deposited the "**LESS Modes**" folder within "**Modes**"

http://ge.tt/3YxFNRH/v/0

Comment: you can simply click "Import" under "Colors" and select any file I have given on my answer... it's that easy!

Comment: As I said earlier in the comments, I was unable to "import" less.SEESTYLE into "colors" from any of the sources you provided or others that I had found.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking, the question is not really understandable.

Are you looking for a way to open `less` files in Coda and make it to correctly hightlight the source with the correct coloring?

> How about [Jason Robb SEEStyles](https://github.com/jasonrobb/Coda-SEEStyles) or import the [less style](https://github.com/DraStudio/Twilight-Seestyles/blob/master/LESS.seestyle) from [Twilight-Seestyles](https://github.com/DraStudio/Twilight-Seestyles)?

Are you looking to compile `less` to `css` within Coda?

> How about a script for [AlfredApp](http://support.alfredapp.com/extensions)?

Comment: Not quite sure how it was confusing. I use LESS.app for less compiling. Coda does not having syntax highlighting for CSS/LESS. I would like Coda to highlight syntax within a .less file.

Comment: That unintentionally sounded snotty, sorry. I updated the question so it was a little clearer.

Comment: "I would like Coda to highlight syntax within a .less file" - so the 2 Seestyles that I point out, works fine, right?

Comment: @ZachShallbetter wouldn't that just be a matter of not knowing how to import it? I'm at work (windows), let me get home and I will take some screen shoots of it so you know how to do it.

Comment: It didn't have anything to do with the import I tried several different versions. It consistently gave me an "unable to import" message.

Comment: SEEStyles won't import unless they are tied to an existing syntax highlighting mode. These are stored in `Coda.app/Contents/Resources/Modes`, `/Library/Application Support/Coda/Modes`, and `~/Library/Application Support/Coda/Modes`. With in each .mode directory, there is a `ModeSettings.xml` file that specifies the file endings that the mode is valid for.