# Coda syntax highlighting for Silverstripe

Tags: syntax-highlighting, silverstripe, coda

I've just moved onto a new machine. On my old work horse, I had Silverstripe template (.ss) files following HTML syntax highlighting in Coda. I can't for the life of me remember how I turned this on (I remember it was something I did myself though). Google has turned up no results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you go to the bottom left hand corner of the editor, you can change the syntax highlighting mode for a particular file to anything you please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE: The real way**

In Coda, open Preferences, go to Editor, at the bottom, add a Custom Syntax Mode.

---

As per [this](http://www.djchoi.com/code/more-syntax-highlighting-for-coda) guide:

1. Right click on `Coda.app` in `/Applications` and select `Show Package Contents`
2. Navigate to `Contents/Resources/Modes/HTML.mode/Contents/Resources`
3. Open ModeSettings.xml
4. Add `<extension>ss</extension>` to the list of extensions.

Or, make your mode (eg, SilverStripe.mode) and put it in `~/Library/Application Support/Coda/Modes`

Or, copy HTML.mode to `~/Library/Application Support/Coda/Modes` and then modify it, to preserve the original.

(For system-wide changes without modifying the application bundle, create the directory `/Library/Application Support/Coda/Modes` and put .mode directories there.)

Comment: @Fraser I played around some more on my machine. If you have <SomeLang>.mode in the application bundle and in `~/Library/Application Support/Coda/`, the latter takes precedence. One advantage to that last solution (that I added after your comment) is that it should avoid the problem of updates to Coda clobbering your setup. I think constructing your own mode would be the best, but that could be quite the challenge.

Comment: @Fraser I just figured out how you're really supposed to do this. Please check my update.